# Using ForkJoin with map in post request - angular 8

Tags: angular, rxjs, fork-join

I have a module that sends many requests and the order goes like this:

1st request saves most of the data and returns an Id that will be sent in the other requests.
In my .ts file:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.datosOferta = this.fb.group({
      ...
      domicilio_empleo: ['option1'],
      conocimiento: this.fb.array([]),
      experiencia: this.fb.array([]),
   });
   this.conocimiento.push(this.fb.control(null));
   .... // more data pushed to this 2 arrays + more data
 }

get conocimiento() {
    return this.datosOferta.get('conocimiento') as FormArray;
  }

save() {  
   let dataPost = {...this.datosOferta.value};
   this.service.save1(dataPost).subscribe((res: any)=>{
        if(res.result) {
          this.service.setId(res.id); 
          
         // **** I have 2 input arrays that need to do this map
          this.conocimiento.value.map( (x, idx) => {
            let _idiomaObj = {
              idOferta: this.service.id,
              idIdioma: this.datosOferta.controls.idiomaComponent.value[idx],
              idIdiomaCert: this.datosOferta.controls.certificado.value[idx],
            }
            this.service.save(_idiomaObj).subscribe( respuesta => {
              console.log(respuesta)
            })
          })

          this.service.anotherSave(data).subscribe( res => { console.log(res) }

          // if all are succes 
          this.router.navigate(['/next-page']);
```

I need to wait till all the maps and the other function end succesfully to run to the next page but I'm not sure how to mix this maps with ForkJoin, any ideas are very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
const requestsArray = this.conocimiento.value.map((x, idx) => {
    const _idiomaObj = {
        idOferta: this.service.id,
        idIdioma: this.datosOferta.controls.idiomaComponent.value[idx],
        idIdiomaCert: this.datosOferta.controls.certificado.value[idx],
    }

    return this.service.save(_idiomaObj);
});

const anotherRequest = this.service.anotherSave(data);

forkJoin([...requestsArray, anotherRequest]).subscribe(results => {
    console.log(results);
    this.router.navigate(['/next-page']);
});
```

should do the job.